# Get-ScheduledTask error on local environment with PSVersion 4.0

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I can not execute Get-ScheduledTask command by local environment.
However I can execute it to remote servers from local environment.

Command(to remote servers)

```
> $c = New-CimSession -ComputerName "host name" -Credential xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $c -TaskName "taskname"
```

Command(to local)

```
> Get-ScheduledTask
```

Error

```
+ Get-ScheduledTask
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask) [Get-ScheduledTask], CimException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,Get-ScheduledTask
```

Questions
1) What is the cause of this error?
2) Why I can execute the command remotely?
Please let me know if you need more information to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Google seems to suggest that this is due to missing or corrupt .NET framework components on your local machine. I suggest you try repairing or reinstalling the .NET framework.

Comment: As Mark told, its because of corrupt dot net. Try [Step by Step process to repair dotnet](http://www.daktronics.com/support/kb/Pages/How%20to%20repair%20-NET%20Framework%204-0.aspx)

Comment: I tried to repair my .NET framework along the link you provided but the result is same.

Comment: My OS version is windows7 so I can not use this command. right?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/jj649808(v=wps.630).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command can not execute on Windows7.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/jj649808(v=wps.630).aspx